# External Javascript Libraries (cdnjs) not being reached by html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

I have been trying to add some html and javascript to my website so users can draw some shapes. I found a really good sample to work from on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77vg88mc/34/). When I run the code on JSFiddle, it works perfectly, but when I ran it myself on my browser (I tried Edge, Firefox, and Chrome) it did not work.
When I ran it myself, I included all the scripts and css into one html file because thats the only way to add it to my Wix website. The scripts (local javascript, and external cdn libraries) where together in the body section of html. All the tutorials I found make it seem like it's OK to use the CDN libraries. I'm positive my issue has something to do with the connection to the CDN libraries, so how would I fix it?

Here is code:

```js
    var roof = null;
    var roofPoints = [];
    var lines = [];
    var lineCounter = 0;
    var drawingObject = {};
    drawingObject.type = "";
    drawingObject.background = "";
    drawingObject.border = "";

    function Point(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    

    $("#poly").click(function () {
        if (drawingObject.type == "roof") {
            drawingObject.type = "";
            lines.forEach(function(value, index, ar){
                 canvas.remove(value);
            });
            //canvas.remove(lines[lineCounter - 1]);
            roof = makeRoof(roofPoints);
            canvas.add(roof);
            canvas.renderAll();
        } else {
            drawingObject.type = "roof"; // roof type
        }
    });


    // canvas Drawing
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-tools');
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    
    fabric.util.addListener(window,'dblclick', function(){ 
            drawingObject.type = "";
            lines.forEach(function(value, index, ar){
                 canvas.remove(value);
            });
            //canvas.remove(lines[lineCounter - 1]);
            roof = makeRoof(roofPoints);
            canvas.add(roof);
            canvas.renderAll();
      
        console.log("double click");
        //clear arrays
         roofPoints = [];
         lines = [];
         lineCounter = 0;
        
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
        if (drawingObject.type == "roof") {
            canvas.selection = false;
            setStartingPoint(options); // set x,y
            roofPoints.push(new Point(x, y));
            var points = [x, y, x, y];
            lines.push(new fabric.Line(points, {
                strokeWidth: 3,
                selectable: false,
                stroke: 'red'
            }).setOriginX(x).setOriginY(y));
            canvas.add(lines[lineCounter]);
            lineCounter++;
            canvas.on('mouse:up', function (options) {
                canvas.selection = true;
            });
        }
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function (options) {
        if (lines[0] !== null && lines[0] !== undefined && drawingObject.type == "roof") {
            setStartingPoint(options);
            lines[lineCounter - 1].set({
                x2: x,
                y2: y
            });
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    });

    function setStartingPoint(options) {
        var offset = $('#canvas-tools').offset();
        x = options.e.pageX - offset.left;
        y = options.e.pageY - offset.top;
    }

    function makeRoof(roofPoints) {

        var left = findLeftPaddingForRoof(roofPoints);
        var top = findTopPaddingForRoof(roofPoints);
        roofPoints.push(new Point(roofPoints[0].x,roofPoints[0].y))
        var roof = new fabric.Polyline(roofPoints, {
        fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        stroke:'#58c'
        });
        roof.set({
            
            left: left,
            top: top,
           
        });


        return roof;
    }

    function findTopPaddingForRoof(roofPoints) {
        var result = 999999;
        for (var f = 0; f < lineCounter; f++) {
            if (roofPoints[f].y < result) {
                result = roofPoints[f].y;
            }
        }
        return Math.abs(result);
    }

    function findLeftPaddingForRoof(roofPoints) {
        var result = 999999;
        for (var i = 0; i < lineCounter; i++) {
            if (roofPoints[i].x < result) {
                result = roofPoints[i].x;
            }
        }
        return Math.abs(result);
    }
```

```css
.canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="poly"  title="Draw Polygon" ">Draw Polygon </button>


<label style="color:blue"><b>Press double click to close shape and stop</b></label>
<canvas id="canvas-tools" class="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

**EDIT**

So, in the html file I put everything inside the `body` tag. The libraries are also included before the javascript. I get the error "Unable to get property 'x' of undefined or null reference" when I double-click to close the shape. I'm positive its because no points are added when I click in the canvas

Comment: Where is the javascript in respect to the html?

Comment: You have to include the libraries before the script. Beyond that, I can't tell what's causing an error unless you share what the error is...

Comment: So, in the html file I put everything inside the <body></body> tag. The libraries are also included before the javascript. I get the error "Unable to get property 'x' of undefined or null reference" when I double-click to close the shape. I'm positive its because no points are added when I click in the canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wix does not allow using Cloudflare. The following link has more detail.

https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-cloudflare-support

Wix has some limited API to work with HTML elements
https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-working-with-the-html-element

if you want to run it on a separate page (not on wix) and scripts are loaded try to wrap your javascript code in :

```
<script>
$(function() { 
     //your code here 
     var roof = null;
     var roofPoints = [];
     var lines = [];
     var lineCounter = 0;
     var drawingObject = {};
     ...
     ...

});
</script>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but the libraries weren't even working when I ran the html file by itself and not on my Wix website

Comment: if you want to run it on a separate page (not on wix) and scripts are loaded try to wrap your javascript code in :

$(function() {
    //your code here
});

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you.  I also tried it out on Wix and it worked